# Who or what were Primus and Unicron?

Tags: transformers

The most iconic of Transformers questions ,at least in my opinion:

Who is Primus? What was his purpose? Was he an Autobot?

On the other hand, Who is Unicron? What was his purpose? Was he a Decepticon?

What are the backstories of these two characters?

Comment: You've seen the original movie right? At least for unicron he seemed to be an entity of his own. His converting megatron appeared to be self serving and not necessarily as a fellow decepticon. The transformers wiki adds nothing in the way of back story for him or his "brother" - however that works

Comment: If you mean the 1986 version ,No I haven't watched it yet. But I'm familiar with the two characters.=)

Comment: Yes, the one true transformers movie. Look for it. It's awesome and boasts a proud soundtrack of inspirational butt rock by the wizard of motivational music Stan Bush. Great voice cast too.

Comment: Why is it only the true transformers movie?

Comment: Because it is. Like any franchise with a root in nostalgia, whatever reboots come 20 years later will always just be fluff, even if they are entertaining. Those of us who remember transformers from the comics and tv show will scoff at what they do to the characters to make them marketable for today. Even James Cameron is taunting us with Battle Angel. I'll see it, but I doubt I'll feel it does nostalgia any justice. And I'm dreading the rumor of a live action Robotech... activate defensive matrix...

Comment: TRANSFORMERS: THE BASICS on Primus may be of interest to you. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Z74FQyEs6nA

Answer (score 4):

So, I read it in the US comics, which were the *second* iteration of the story, though not significantly different in detail, only in the narrator. Since then the story has evolved greatly, specifically with respect to the cinematic universe. The Transformers wiki explains it better than I can:

https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Primus#Marvel_The_Transformers_comics

What follows is my original from-memory response, which can be considered a fair paraphrase of the wiki's text, sans newer details (such as the Fallen).

It is explained in the comics (sorry, I'm on mobile with no references handy). Unicron and Primus were godlike beings at war with each other. Primus tricked Unicron into a plantary body, along with himself in another) in order to stop him, but after many aeons they both learned how to manipulate their new corporeal forms. Unicron made himself the planet killer; Primus prepared himself for the inevitable battle by giving birth to sentient robotic beings. It was long after this, as Primus slumbered from his efforts, that the Deception faction formed and tore Cybertron  (Primus ' body) into a shattered war zone.

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer, through laptop. Like putting sources, expanding your answer, etc..

Comment: This is exactly how i remember it from the 1980s UK comics.

Comment: Yes, I will edit it as soon as I can. It may take a week though.